# Ivy not able to resolve

Tags: ivy

I am trying handy with IVY and I have set up my ivy de in springsource tool suite.

While trying to build my workspace, I am getting the following error.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid classpath publish/export dependency C:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/jstl/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar. The project contains another dependency with the same archive name. Web     P/Web   Classpath Dependency Validator Message

Any help, in this regard, is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Sandip

Comment: could you please send the ivy.xml file and the ant file.
Potentially, you have multiple dependency on the same jar with different versions. (check ivy:report for that).

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue, although this happened to me primarily when I have multiple projects open in my workspace.  If I simply remove "Classpath Dependency Validator" from the list in Project -> Validation -> Validators (for project specific validators), this error goes away for me.  Other posts have mentioned that you can also manually exclude other dependencies from other modules in your ivy.xml, but that seems a bit messier for me, and unnecessary.